# Locus of an Equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry

Bouncing off of another question I had [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3206325/equation-involving-ratios), I wondered what would be the equation of the locus of this equation: $$0 = b + ax - dy - cxy$$ Specifically $$0=xy-6y+6x-3$$ I would like a way to derive it. Also, if it is possible, may someone please give me a name for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, 
$$ (x-6)(y+6) = xy -6y+6x - 36 $$  You have
$$  0 = xy-6y+6x-3  $$
Subtract!

$$ (x-6)(y+6) = -33 $$
called a hyperbola, in the same way that $xy = 1$ is a hyperbola. Just moved a bit, stretched a bit.

Let's check a point. My version has $-3 \cdot 11 = -33,$ so we can take $x=3, y=5.$ The original
$xy-6y+6x -3$ becomes $3 \cdot 5 - 6 \cdot 5 + 6 \cdot 3 - 3 = 15 -30+18 - 3=0$

Comment: Oh, is there a way to do this without factoring. Edit: I meant how to get solutions to the hyperbola without factoring.

Comment: @QuoteDave Another way is to eliminate the term $xy$ and then complete squares. This will still be a hyperbola, but rotated. Why doesn't factoring appeal to you, especially when it's an elementary case of it?

Comment: Because I am trying to work on a better factorization method, so factorization would seem redundant.